# Django url issue if included trailing slash

Tags: javascript, python, django, url

I have this url in one of the Django app with trailing slash

```
path('quiz/timeupdate/',updateTime.as_view(),name='timeupdates')
```

and i'm calling this via javascript  post method using navigator.sendBeacon. This as well has a trailing slash

```
navigator.sendBeacon('http://127.0.0.1:8000/quiz/timeupdate/',form_data)
```

it is showing me this error

```
Not Found: /quiz/timeupdate/
```

if i remove trailing slash from both python and javascript then it works fine else it throws the above error

Comment: Is the url above in the root url.py or inside url.py of an app ?

Comment: inside   url.py of an app

Comment: can you please share your root url.py ?

Comment: `path('',include('QuizApp.urls')),`

Comment: Does your `settings.py` contains an `APPEND_SLASH` setting?